# continuously embedding

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed vector spaces, with norms $||·||_X$ and $||·||_Y$ respectively. If there are constants $C_1, C_2≥0$ such that $||·||_Y \leq C_1||·||^{1/2}_X+C_2||·||^2_X$ for every $x\in X$, can we say $X$ is continuously embedded into $Y$? Thank you!

Comment: notice we do not have a linear control of norms but linear by quadratic, for example. Thanks!

Comment: Is it $\|\cdot\|_X\le C\|\cdot\|_Y^2$ or $\|\cdot\|_Y\le C\|\cdot\|_X^2$?

Answer (score 4):

By homogeneity (take $\lambda x$ instead of $x$ for $x\neq 0$), we get that $X$ reduces to the trivial space (we divide by $|\lambda|$, then let $\lambda\to 0$).